# JavaScript templating

Tags: javascript, mustache, hogan.js

I was trying to convince a fellow co-worker into using Mustache/Hogan in the front-end of a project and I proposed the following:

Having a templates.js file, which could roughly look like this:

```
var tpl_alert = '<div class="alert">{{msg}}</div>';
var tpl_welcome = '<p class="user-{{type}}">Welcome, {{name}}</p>';
...
```

Then, we would include templates.js and use the corresponding tpl in the Mustache/Hogan.js rendering.

My proposal was turned down, since we're hardcoding html templates into js variables. 
Is this really that bad? Which are other alternatives to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, putting your templates in javascript variables inside a static JavaScript file makes it difficult to maintain your templates. You need to worry about string escaping whenever you want to make a simple change. And 1 syntax error will crash your app.

However, putting all your templates in a single JavaScript file is the fastest way to load your templates.

Your alternatives are:

1. Storing your templates in seperate files and generating the static template.js file as a prebuild step.
2. Loading your html template files async through AJAX into javascript variables.
3. Using a library like [Require.js](http://www.requirejs.org) that will load your templates asynchronously as needed into variables.

Comment: Thanks, I took alternative 2 also as a valid option, having the obvious drawback that you need an extra ajax call, tho. We'll see how this performs.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way of doing this is to create a separate template file that can be loaded dynamically in development and baked into pure js for production.

Specifically I use [eco](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) templates (I wouldn't recommend them unless you're familiar with coffee script) and [Stitch for node.js](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch). Stitch supports custom engines tied to file extensions, so when it finds an eco file in my project directory it compiles it into a Javascript function. I can now include that function in any other part of my application using the stitch provided `require` function using the original path of the eco file. So if the template resided in `src/views/listItem.eco` I would run `var listItemView = require('views/listItem');` to fetch it and use it like this

```
var html = listItemView({item: items[i]});
$someElement.html(html);
```

You could use require.js instead of stitch if course, or any other similar framework.